# Text missing from downloaded svg file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, vector, svg

I've downloaded a [.svg logo](https://www.lnb.lt/templates/vaikbiblioteka/images/logo.svg) (I've inverted the #fff colours of the element to #000 before downloading) that I want to add to Illustrator/InDesign from a webpage.

It loads up fine in a browser, such as edge or Firefox, but the text part (that's in a separate group) goes missing whenever I try to place it in an InDesign graphics box, or when opening it in Illustrator. If I try to select a group that should be the text, it's a little invisible dot in the corner of the document, which I can move, but can't resize. Is there anything I can do apart from typing in the text myself?

[When opening in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tyCy.png):
[image: When opening in browser]

Text missing in Illustrator:

[image: Text missing in Illustrator]

Little dot in the corner of Illustrator:

[image: Little dot in the corner of Illustrator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's wrong here. But Illustrator doesn't like it for some reason. Illustrator doesn't even seem to import the paths that make up the text, they're simply missing. It must have something to do with the way the SVG is constructed.

Anyway, I got it to work by opening in Inkscape (which is free), selected everything, changed the fill to black, then I did *File > Clean up document*, then I saved as Plain SVG from Inkscape, then it opens in Illustrator just fine.

[image]

I've shared [the SVG here](https://svgshare.com/i/WME.svg) if you want it.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, so I've also tried ungrouping the text part, that did the trick for whatever reason. Might've worked without the inkscape too, with just editing the html. Thanks for the suggention.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the text is there, its just flattened white path on white background.
Try to run the file through some SVG cleaner / minimizer / converter. File looks ok when opened in text editor.

Comment: I tried to use one site, the outcome was the same. Doing it in inkscape and ungrouping did the trick for me.